# When creating a 'query parameter' can it be specified to a container tag rather than just individually to each 'a href' tag

Tags: html

When creating a 'query parameter' can it be specified to a container tag rather than just individually to each 'a href' tag.

I am using a menu [MenuA.html] with many 'a href' links each containing the same 'query parameter'.

```
<a href="./Page1.html?MyRedictedFrom=MenuA">MenuA Child Page1</a>
<a href="./Page2.html?MyRedictedFrom=MenuA">MenuA Child Page2</a>
<a href="./Page3.html?MyRedictedFrom=MenuA">MenuA Child Page3</a>
......etc.
```

Is it possible to instead dispense with having to add the "?MyRedictedFrom=MenuA" 'query parameter" to 
each individual 'a href' link and instead do one of three things? 
(A - good) Globally for the page, declare all 'a href' when clicked append that common 'query parameter'. 
(B-better) That restricted to one container only, say that of the 'article tag', all of the 'a href' 
contained only within that container append the desired common 'query parameter'. 
(C-best) Given I am using more that one set of 'nav tag' containers [a content section of links and, 
another bottom section of site navigation links each enclosed in 'nav tag(s)'] the nicest solution, if
possible, would be to target the 'a href' appending to take place in just one of the 'nav tag' sections
specified.

Gratitude @CertainPerformance. I wish not so much to redo the working code on those given single common child pages I know can be invoked from either a parent MenuA or a parent MenuB. But rather, going back to my initial question in this context, using the already working outgoing 'query parameter' string(s) appended now individually to each parent 'a href', I only wish optionally (A)or(B)or(C) to have the 'query parameter' string auto set via the page load itself or by specifying it to a tagged container. I will add my present working code to my question area as comments are limited.

zMenuA.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>zMenuA.html [Acknowledgement @Andu Andrici]</title>
</head>
<body>

<article>
<nav>

<a href="./zSameTarget.html?redictedFrom=zMenuA">zMenuA.html invoking zSameTarget.html</a>
<!-- other links as well -->

</nav>
</article>

<nav></nav>
</body>
</html>
```

zMenuB.html would almost be a duplicate of zMenuA except essentially its appended 'query parameter' string would be: ?redictedFrom=zMenuB. It is zMenuA and zMenuB I would hope to modify to have the parameter string added to the (A-good) document onload, or (B-better) the article tag, or (C-best) the first nav tag.

The common child in this case seems need no change and is shown in its functional working completion below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>zSameTarget.html [Acknowledgement @Andu Andrici]</title>
<style></style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var MyAppendedUrlMarker = window.location.search

    if (MyAppendedUrlMarker === '?redictedFrom=zMenuA') {
    onload = function () {
        var MyElement = 
document.getElementById("MyDisplayOnOff0").style.display = "inline";
        var MyElement = 
document.getElementById("MyDisplayOnOff1").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    if (MyAppendedUrlMarker === '?redictedFrom=zMenuB') { 
    onload = function () {
        var MyElement = 
document.getElementById("MyDisplayOnOff0").style.display = "none";
        var MyElement = 
document.getElementById("MyDisplayOnOff1").style.display = "inline";
        }        
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>

<p style="white-space:pre-wrap;">
This is the child page 'zSameTarget.html' with this content showing 
the same; BUT, at the bottom, with different content [a navigation link] 
being visible and active, solely dictated by which parent page invoked 
this page. To whit, whether in opening this page, an [a href ....] was 
clicked on 'zMenuA.html', or if it came from a click originating from 
'zMenuB.html' instead. NOTE: running this page alone will show two links. 
It is meant to show only one link. Therefore, first open 'zMenuA.html' 
or 'zMenuB.html' and then link to this page from either one of them. As
indicated, depending on the page chosen, one will find it has produced a 
different content [link in this case] visible at the bottom.</p><br/>

    <div>
<a id="MyDisplayOnOff0" href="./Menu%20-%20Rivers%20of%20Mind%20and%20Heart.html">Rivers of Mind and Heart</a> 
<br/>
<a id="MyDisplayOnOff1" href="./Menu%20-%20Of%20Lila%20and%20the%20Void.html">Of Lila and the Void</a> 
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using just HTML.... no. Using javascript, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Javascript, you might consider using event delegation - when an `a` inside a particular container is clicked, save that container's name (like `MenuA`) in SessionStorage, and then you can try to retrieve that SessionStorage value when on the other page. For example:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.matches('.menu > a')) {
    return;
  }
  const menuName = target.parentElement.id;
  alert('Clicked on ' + menuName);
  sessionStorage.redirectedFrom = menuName;
});
```

```html
<div id="MenuA" class="menu">
  <a href="./Page1.html">MenuA Child Page1</a>
  <a href="./Page2.html">MenuA Child Page2</a>
  <a href="./Page3.html">MenuA Child Page3</a>
</div>
<div id="MenuB" class="menu">
  <a href="./Page1.html">MenuB Child Page1</a>
  <a href="./Page2.html">MenuB Child Page2</a>
  <a href="./Page3.html">MenuB Child Page3</a>
</div>
```

And then, on each of the child pages, on pageload, check to see if something's in `redirectedFrom`:

```
const { redirectedFrom } = sessionStorage;
// do something with redirectedFrom, if it exists

sessionStorage.removeItem('redirectedFrom');
```

If the query parameter is used by the server, and not by the client, then you can change the `href` onclick instead:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.matches('.menu > a')) {
    return;
  }
  const menuName = target.parentElement.id;
  const newHref = `${target.href}?redirectedFrom=${menuName}`;
  target.href = newHref;
  alert('Clicked on ' + menuName + ', redirecting to ' + newHref);
});
```

```html
<div id="MenuA" class="menu">
  <a href="./Page1.html">MenuA Child Page1</a>
  <a href="./Page2.html">MenuA Child Page2</a>
  <a href="./Page3.html">MenuA Child Page3</a>
</div>
<div id="MenuB" class="menu">
  <a href="./Page1.html">MenuB Child Page1</a>
  <a href="./Page2.html">MenuB Child Page2</a>
  <a href="./Page3.html">MenuB Child Page3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Gratitude @CertainPerformance. I wish not so much to redo the working code on those given single common child pages I know can be invoked from either a parent MenuA or a parent MenuB. But rather, going back to my initial question in this context, using the already working outgoing 'query parameter' string(s) appended now individually to each parent 'a href', I only wish optionally (A)or(B)or(C) to have the 'query parameter' string auto set via the page load itself or by specifying it to a tagged container. I will add my present working code to my question area as comments here are limited.

Comment: Then use the last snippet in the answer, which changes the `href` when the `a` is clicked on

Comment: Thank you @CertainPreformance. I marked your answer as the correct solution. It was in depth, knowledgeable , elegant, and functional. Since it incorporated the tweak I desired in sending parent-id  information forward to an 'a href'd' child page by using a container tag declaration, rather than individually coded 'a href(s), I changed my code from using 'query parameter' to your suggested use of 'sessionStorage'. I did remove your dutiful memory clearing "sessionStorage.removeItem('redirectedFrom');" to the top of the menu script as a page refresh create havoc leaving it on the child page.

Comment: Needed code to fix the answer I accepted. sessionStorage (W3C...) "stores the data for only one session. The data is deleted when the user closes the specific browser tab"; which, is excellent and naturally expiring. Freeing memory by adding the general good coding practice line of 'sessionStorage.removeItem('redirectedFrom');' is basically making the stored information non-persistent from there on in that session. In my practical testing, including that 'removeItem' totally wrecks havoc if the page is either refreshed, or skipped back and forth to with the browser back and forward arrows.